# What does this function return?

Tags: javascript

```
    rowData = []

    function something () {
    return rowData
    }
```

**Update:**

Now lets take the Array contains a lot of Objects. So we say that this would return an Array of Objects.

I am just confused a lot. Does this return an Object or Array of Object Or just an Array.

Comment: It returns `rowData` which is an array. It does not matter what is in the array. An array is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is an **array literal** so that function returns an empty Array. In JavaScript, arrays are really objects and they are a little different than traditional arrays.

From Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

> JavaScript provides an object that has
>   some array-like characteristics. It
>   converts array subscripts into strings
>   that are used to make properties.

And...

> Unlike most other languages,
>   JavaScript's array length is not an
>   upper bound. If you store an element
>   with a subscript that is greater than
>   or equal to the current length, the
>   length will increase to contain the
>   new element. There is not array bounds
>   error.

Answer (score 2):

It returns whatever the current value of `rowData` is.

That variable is initialized as an empty array. It might change by the time the function is called.

An array is a specific type of object.

Answer (score 2):

It returns an empty array from your function. Please note that the value returned from this function will change if anything changes the rowData symbol in the global scope.